# php imap_open not working on server for outlook email

Tags: php, outlook, imap

I am trying to fetch email content in my `PHP` script using `imap_open`. I have the below code:

```
$hostname = '{imap-mail.outlook.com:993/ssl}'; 
$email = 'rohitmittaltech@outlook.com';
$password = 'mypassword';

$inbox = imap_open($hostname, $email, $password) or die('Cannot connect to PACNET: ' . imap_last_error());
```

This code is working very fine on my local server. When I uploaded the code on server, it does not work. I have checked that `IMAP` and `OPENSSL` are enabled on  server. I am getting below error when running this code:

```
Cannot connect to PACNET: Can not authenticate to IMAP server: AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

I have tried several things but it doesn't help me. Errors appearing in `imap_errors` are:

```
    [0] => Retrying PLAIN authentication after AUTHENTICATE failed.
    [1] => Retrying PLAIN authentication after AUTHENTICATE failed.
    [2] => Can not authenticate to IMAP server: AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: did you tried imap_errors()?

Comment: updated question to make it very clear.

Comment: The major email providers use a wide variety of security measures.  Generally, as these services are intended for end users, they often restrict logins from cloud type services, since users don’t run their email clients there.  To access them from anywhere, you would probably need to implement OAuth/ADAL and it may not be worth it,.